# Linking third party CSV reader to a progress bar

Tags: c#, csv, progress-bar, streamreader

I found a well-written CSV parser/reader from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) written by Sebastien Lorion.

What I like of this CSV parser is that I could easily bind it to a DataGrid like:

```
using (CachedCsvReader csv = new
   CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(txtChosenFile.Text), true))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = csv;
        }
```

Which is what I need in my project because I want my users to preview it before committing it to the Database.

However, since it takes a while to load a file I need to provide at least a feedback to my user using a Progress Bar. Unfortunately, it is only one liner to get the `CachedCsvReader` class which make it difficult for me to link or update a progress bar as the reading of the csv file progresses.

If it is just a simple `CsvReader` class it would be easy to update my progress Bar like:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
            using (CsvReader csv = new
       CsvReader(sr, true))
            {
                double progress = (double) sr.BaseStream.Position /  (double) sr.BaseStream.Length;
                progressBar1.Value = (int)progress*100;
            }

        }
```

However, since I am using a `CachedCsvReader` and it is only one liner (or two) to get upload the csv reader without having an information on the stream position and length then I could not update my progress bar.

So, what would be the best way to connect my progress bar to my CachedCsvReader?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are initiating the read from a method called `Open`, following should work. It uses a timer control to poll the read position every 1 sec.:

```
private StreamReader sr;
public void Open()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Enabled = true;
      timer.Start();
    using (this.sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        using (CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(sr, true))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = csv;
        }
    }
      timer.Stop();
    timer.Enabled = false;
    timer.Tick -= new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null != this.sr)
    {
        double progress = (double)sr.BaseStream.Position / (double)sr.BaseStream.Length;
        progressBar1.Value = (int)progress * 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @loopedcode for your response. I tried your code but it did not even go to timer_Tick event (I tried to debug it). I tried to make the Interval smaller and to no avail. But honestly your idea is good.

Comment: I can see a typo, its missing a call to timer.Start();

Comment: Updated code, see if it works. If it still doesn't enter the timer block, then your file might be getting read very fast.

Comment: Same result. But you have given me something to start with and I thank you for that.